# How can I avoid SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in this generic method?

Tags: java, generics

How can I get rid of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in this method?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> Worker<T> findSimilarWorker(Worker<T> worker) {
    // The variable workers is a Set<Worker<?>>
    for(Worker<?> w : workers) {
        // The following line is unchecked cast
        if(w.isSimilar(worker)) return (Worker<T>) w;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you really want to get rid of it then you should change your java version .

Comment: did you try `for (Worker<? extends T> w : workers){}` ?

Comment: @pKs I'm on Android, so I'm stuck with Java 6

Comment: @nicopico that won't compile because workers is a Set<Worker<?>> (not Set<Worker<T>>)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `workers` is defined to yield `Worker`s of type `?`, you're simply going to *need* the type cast. The compiler is right in warning you about this, as `workers` might contain a `Worker` of a different type (though `workers` is not shown, I'm assuming its not of type `T`).

(short version: you can't, not even with an `instanceof` check, which doesn't allow generics)

Comment: If the `Worker` has a method `getTypeOfT()` returning `Class<T>`... can that be of any help?

Comment: I doubt a `Class<T>` will help, but if worker has a method that would essentially cast itself to `Worker<T>`, that might work: `public <T> Worker<T> getOfTypeT() { return (Worker<T>) this; }` (note that a generic type cast like that might get you a `ClassCastException` at runtime on the line of the assignment rather than the cast ;)

Comment: Ow bollocks, never mind, above method will get you the exact warning you started with :P